# 2022: moderação do site em números

Tags: debate, moderação, estatísicas

Ao se despedir do ano antigo e dar boas-vindas ao ano novo, temos [a tradição de compartilhar as estatísticas de moderação do ano anterior](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

Como muitos sabem, sites da rede Stack Exchange são moderados diferente de outros sites na web:

> A rede Stack Exchange foi desenhada para ser auto-regulada, de modo que o custo de moderação do sistema é amortizado em milhares de pequenas porções de esforço diário dos usuários regulares.
> -- [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Isso não elimina totalmente a necessidade de [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), mas significa que a maior parte do trabalho de moderação é realizada por pessoas comuns. Cada vez que todos vocês contribuem para o site te dá acesso a mais privilégios que ajudam neste esforço, os quais produzem um efeito cumulativo que faz uma grande diferença.

Então, ao nos despedirmos de 2022 (como fizemos em janeiro, certo?) E mergulharmos de cabeça em 2023, vamos olhar para trás e ver o que conquistamos como comunidade... vendo algumas [estatísticas *empolgantes*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Abaixo está um detalhamento das ações de moderação realizadas no Stack Overflow em Português nos últimos 12 meses:

| Ação | Moderadores | Comunidade¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Todos os comentários movidos para o chat | 25 | 0 |
| Sinalizações de resposta tratados | 7,871 | 815 |
| Respostas sinalizadas | 4,202 | 4,486 |
| Recompensas canceladas | 10 | 0 |
| Comentários sinalizados tratados | 719 | 53 |
| Comentários deletados⁷ | 1,258 | 2,283 |
| Comentários sinalizados | 429 | 343 |
| Comentários restaurados | 102 | 0 |
| Encaminhamentos para o time de Gerenciamento da Comunidade | 49 | 0 |
| Publicações bumped | 0 | 8,295 |
| Publicações excluídas⁶ | 2,005 | 24,307 |
| Publicações bloqueadas | 120 | 210 |
| Publicações restauradas | 228 | 583 |
| Publicações desbloqueadas | 27 | 19 |
| Perguntas sinalizadas tratadas⁵ | 4,782 | 3,939 |
| Perguntas fechadas | 11,760 | 2,375 |
| Perguntas sinalizadas⁵ | 3,532 | 5,661 |
| Perguntas merged (combinadas) | 5 | 0 |
| Perguntas protegidas | 24 | 227 |
| Perguntas reabertas | 198 | 3 |
| Perguntas desprotegidas | 1 | 0 |
| Revisões redacted (censurado por dados sensíveis) | 55 | 0 |
| Tag destacadas language set | 4 | 0 |
| Sinônimos de Tag criados | 3 | 0 |
| Tags combinadas | 31 | 0 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Votos para fechar" | 171 | 2,228 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Primeiras respostas" | 32 | 4,712 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Primeiras perguntas" | 68 | 16,044 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Respostas tardias" | 19 | 1,819 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Publicações de baixa qualidade" | 56 | 2,581 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Votos para reabrir" | 830 | 1,276 |
| Tarefas de revisão⁴: fila "Edições sugeridas" | 489 | 3,555 |
| Usuários banidos da revisão | 4 | 0 |
| Suspensões de usuário antecipadas | 5 | 0 |
| Usuários contatados | 630 | 0 |
| Usuários excluídos | 59 | 0 |
| Usuários destruídos³ | 23 | 0 |
| Usuários suspensos² | 204 | 30 |

#### Notas de rodapé

¹ "Comunidade" se refere tanto a [membros do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users) *sem* [o diamante próximo ao seus nomes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), e ao sistema automático conhecido como [user #-1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² O sistema suspende um usuário em três circunstâncias: quando o usuário é recriado depois de ser suspenso anteriormente, quando é recriado depois de ser destruído por *spam* ou abuso, ou quando a conta sofre uma suspensão em toda a rede.

³ Um usuário "destruído" ocorre quando há um exclusão de usuário juntamente com tudo que ele publicou: perguntas, respostas, comentários. [Geralmente expedida para se livrar de spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ É contabilizado todas as revisões submetidas (que não foram puladas) - ou seja, as duas revisões necessárias para as Edições Sugeridas contam como 2, pois o objetivo é indicar a frequência das ações de moderação. O mesmo se aplica a sinalizações, etc.

⁵ Inclui sinalizações de fechamento (mas *não* os votos para fechar ou reabrir). A comunidade pode tratar essas sinalizações se pelo menos uma pessoa votar para fechar uma pergunta que possui uma sinalização de voto para fechar.

⁶ Ignora os inúmeros casos em que a publicação é apagada automaticamente em resposta a alguma ação.

⁷ Inclui comentários apagados pelos próprios autores (que também considera algumas sinalizações de comentários que foram tratadas).

#### Leitura adicional:

- Você pode ver [este relatório em outros sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Ou leia [informações detalhadas sobre o número de perguntas fechadas e reabertas em todos os sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Desejo a todos um feliz 2023! ^_^

Comment: Sem querer ser chato mas já sendo: o texto é **basicamente o mesmo** de [anos anteriores](/q/8537/112052), qual a dificuldade de copiar e só mudar os números? Aliás, essa é uma reclamação antiga que sempre é ignorada: até onde sei, há pelo menos três CM's que falam português, e mesmo assim insistem em postar em inglês. Em um post como esse, que basta copiar o texto de outro ano, é pior ainda, passa uma sensação ruim de descaso e desleixo. Cansei de traduzir, sugerir que postem em português e ser ignorado...

Comment: O post é feito com um script, @hkotsubo, para facilitar a publicação em _todos_ os sites. Todos os SOs internacionais acabam por ser postados em inglês por causa disso. Entendo que causa frustração; vou ver se se conseguer optimizar o script para acomodar traduções nos SOs internacionais para o ano que vem.

Comment: Gostaria de saber no caso de fechamento de pergunta onde o último voto for do moderador. Esse fechamento é contabilizado como fechamento realizado pela comunidade, fechamento realizado pela moderação ou fechamento realizado pela comunidade e pela moderação.

Comment: É contado como fechamento realizado pela moderação, @AugustoVasques

Comment: Confesso que achei, no mínimo, hilário um post desse marcar um *meme* do Homer Simpson dizendo que *pode ser provado **qualquer coisa** com estatísticas*.

Comment: @hkotsubo eu peguei alguns trechos da sua tradução lá de 2018. Tem problema?

Comment: não encontrei uma tradução fiel para a palavra "bumped". Ou pelo menos que faz sentido nesse contexto.

Comment: pessoalmente eu não entendi o que significa o bumped nesse contexto. No meu entendimento o "bumped" seria aquela ação de melhorar uma edição (que hoje nas filas não existe mais) seria isso?

Comment: @Danizavtz "bumped" foi traduzido como "levantadas à página principal". É quando o sistema faz a pergunta voltar pra home do site (mais ou menos equivalente ao "up" que o pessoal costuma fazer em fóruns)

Comment: O bump é descrito [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/208518), no ponto "The Community user will bump..."

Comment: ah sim, entrou naquela aba "ativos" é isso?

Comment: @Danizavtz exato, a postagem vai pro topo na homepage default - com título "principais perguntas" - que é a "aba" ativos. O termo "bump" vale para qualquer ação que jogue a postagem no topo. Toda edição dá um "empurrão" na postagem, para que a comunidade tenha oportunidade de avaliar a versão atualizada, e o bot comunidade usa o mesmo mecanismo para movimentar algumas postagens que "pararam no meio do caminho".